# Fetching data from a Core Data entity using relationships

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have two entities in my core data model, `Computer` and `Components`. A computer can have multiple components, so the relationship is set as `to-many`. `Computer` also has an attribute `computerName`.

When adding a component I want the selected computer to appear in the add component view. This add component view is written in SwiftUI and I have this code to create the ManagedObjectContext and to fetch the computer object:

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Computer.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var computerToDisplay: FetchedResults<Computer>
```

I then run the following ForEach loop which I would expect to it to grab a Computer and place it in the Text field

```
    ForEach(computerToDisplay, id: \.self) { computer in
        Text(computer.computerName)
    }
```

With this code, when I attempt to open the add component view I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."
```

Now, I'm loading the add component view from a UIKit ViewController. So I'm not sure if something isn't getting passed through to the add component view.

This is how I'm loading the component view:

```
@IBSegueAction func addComponentSegueAction(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    let swiftUIView = UIHostingController(rootView: AddComponentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc!))
    present(swiftUIView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: AddComponentView())
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you show how you are loading ComponentView in UIKit?

Comment: Just added the method I'm using to load the AddComponentView in UIKit. Thank you for your help. When I present the AddComponentView I get this runtime error: `Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator:`

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Please try my suggestion which I posted as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@IBSegueAction func addComponentSegueAction(_ coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    let swiftUIView = UIHostingController(coder: coder, rootView: AddComponentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc!)
    return swiftUIView
}
```

Seems, you are creating multiple instances of UIHostingViewController with your `AddComponentView()` and returning the one which don't have `AddComponentView()` managedObjectContext in environment.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this works until I build/run the app again. When I do that I get the following error
`executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.` .